# X-axis is squished using the EpiCurve package and influenza_england_1978_school data - how do I make it look like a standard epi curve?

Tags: r

I am using the `influenza_england_1978_school` dataset and the `EpiCurve package` in R. This is my code:

```r
library(EpiCurve)    
library(outbreak) ## for influenza data
data <- influenza_england_1978_school
EpiCurve(x = data, date = "date", freq = "in_bed", period = "day")
```

I am trying to plot the epi curve, but the x-axis is really squished and only displays 2 dates as pictured below.
[image]

Is there a reason the x-axis is so squished together? I checked, the date variable has Date class. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly *why* it's specified that way (maybe so that the little graphical elements representing cases are actually squares?), but apparently `EpiCurve` internally uses `coord_fixed(1)` so that the 1 unit on the x and y axes is represented by the same physical dimensions.  You can override this by specifying `+ coord_cartesian()` ...

```r
e <- EpiCurve(x = data, date = "date", freq = "in_bed", period = "day")
e + coord_cartesian()
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome thank you. I also looked into the square argument within it. My assumption is that the amount of squares it is trying to squeeze in might be a little overwhelming so it just kind of broke it (when I set square = F, I get this exact graph but smoothed surface, no lines). Thanks so much for the help.